# electron phonon interaction

Tags: condensed-matter

I am reading the paper on deriving electron phonon interaction hamiltonian by

Frohlic.http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/royprsa/215/1122/291.full.pdf

Here author has introduced the quantization for complex B field in this paper and claimed to have arrived at the diagonalized form of the hamiltonian. I didn't get the quantization part .I think there is some notational problem. He used w to denote wavevectors and at the sametime in the quantization W sits infront of it.. $$ \vec{B}=\frac{\vec{W}}{w}(2h/2\pi wnvs')^{1/2}\sum_{w} b_{w} e^{iw.r}$$ I think there also should be a creation operartor part as well and that's the reason we will get the kind of term author have claimed to get (only then we need to impose the commutation relation,if there is only this much in B then probably I don't need to impose that at all)..most likely I am missing something here..can anyone help me with it..

thanks.

Edit: I have hamiltonian $H= \int |{div\vec{B}}|^{2}nMs'.\, d^{3}r $

Now We want to quantize it.
So Author have introduced following scheme $$ \vec{B}=\frac{\vec{W}}{w}(2h/2\pi wnvs')^{1/2}\sum_{w} b_{w} e^{iw.r}$$ Using this and writing the integration in the following form
 $$ H=\int(div\vec{B}^{*}div\vec{B}+div\vec{B}div(\vec{B}^{*}) (nMs'/2).\, d^{3}r $$

and then substituting the B we get the following

$$ H=\sum \frac{hs'(\vec{W}.\vec{w})^{2}}{2w^{3}}[b_{w}^{\dagger}b_{w}+b_{w}b_{w}^{\dagger}]$$

Here w is the magnitude of $\vec{W}$... I need the following

$$ H=\sum_{w} \frac{hs'w}{2}[b_{w}^{\dagger}b_{w}+b_{w}b_{w}^{\dagger}]$$

Comment: I guess that $\vec{w}$ is a unit vector that points into the direction of $\vec{B}$ because everything else is a scalar. Then he takes a decomposition into plane waves in that direction. The sum over all $\vec{w}$ means simply that he considers all possible modes in that direction. If you agree with me, Ill put this as an answer.

Comment: I also think that there is no need to add any creation operator. In eq 2.5, there is the modulus squared of $\mathrm{div}\vec{B}$ which will involve the conjugate of $\vec{B}$, hence a $b^\dagger$. But I haven't done any math, it's just a guess (even if I'm pretty sure).

Comment: Then are you saying that W should be inside of the summation???

Comment: Also I agree  $b^{\dagger}$ will come from $B^{*}$ but you see the form he has given that will not come..this will give me only one term say $b^{\dagger} b$ or the other way not both at the same time..

Comment: Sorry I think I interpreted the first part wrong....You said $\vec{W}$ is in the direction of $\vec{B}$.. Then a decomposition..so the $\vec{W}$ he used to denote wavevectors and the one to say the direction are different???? Also I have an immediate problem in evaluating divw since I donno how div should act on w...isn't it??

Comment: More context into *what* the author is doing (so that we don't have to DL & read the paper) and what you don't understand ("I'm missing something" to far too vague) is probably going to be needed.

Comment: sorry when I wrote $\vec{w}$, I meant $\vec{W}$. the first $\vec{W}$ isn't inside the sum. The index of the sum refers to all modes that are parallel to $\vec{W}$, if you were to work on a finite size system of length $L$ in the direction $\vec{W}$, then the modes would be $\vec{W}_n = \frac{2\pi}{L}n \vec{W},\, n\in\mathrm{Z}$. Then $\vec{r}$ is colinear to $\vec{W}$ so that the divergence applied on $\vec{B}$ expressed in the plane wave basis is well defined.

Comment: Please don't use block equations in comments.

Comment: after another look, I think that $\vec{W}/w$ is the unit vector. edit: you wrote it in your question... I didn't see it.

Comment: @PinkFloyd yes that is a unit vector and I have done the calculation and wrote what I got in the post... where I have acted the divergence on $e^{i\vec{w}.{r}}$ and got the expression... Can you tell me if that is right??

Comment: I also but at the last step... I did things a bit differently. I have $div(B)div(B*)$ where the fraction $(\vec{W}/w)$ times $(\vec{W}/w)$ gives one because it's the same unit vector. then I'm left with the two sums over $\vec{W'}$ and $\vec{W''}$ which will simplify after the Delta Kroneker coming from the integration over $\vec{r}$. Then I have $\frac{1}{w}\sum_{\vec{W}'}\vec{W'}^2(b_{\vec{W'}}^{\dagger}b_{\vec{W'}} +b_{\vec{W'}}b_{\vec{W'}}^\dagger )$ but I don't see the reason why it can be further simplified.

Comment: Hi  PinkFloyd, How did you get two terms just writing divB div(B^{*})....You have to take two combinations meaning 1/2 $(div B div B^{*} +other way)$ and then you have two terms ...is that right? This is the first thing...

Comment: 2nd thing is when gradient acts on $e^{i\vec{w}.\vec{r}}$ we get things like $\vec{W}.\vec{w}$...how did you simplify this??